# Rspec fails, but view works fine: undefined method `courses' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

There is a model called courses, which users can take and as a result I have `@user.courses` - It works on the view for static-pages-home, as it allows me to list the courses via the partial listed below. However I am getting errors in my rspec tests as a result.

Controller

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @user = current_user
    @courses = @user.courses
  end

end
```

Rspec Error

```
1) Static pages should have the right links on the layout
   Failure/Error: visit root_path
   NoMethodError:
   undefined method `courses' for nil:NilClass
   # ./app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:4:in `home'
   # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Rspec Spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "Home page" do

    before { visit root_path} <<<error here (rb:55)
  end
end
```

View Partial (That works)

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="span8">
  <% if @courses.any? %>
  <ul class="courses">
    <%- @courses.each do |course| %>
    <%= link_to course.title, course_path(course) %>
    <%- end%>
     </ul>
   <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is the current user set up in your specs?

Comment: Do you see why Dave Newton is asking you that?  It's because `current_user` is returning `nil`, which is why you're getting the error you're getting.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I am not exactly sure how current user is set up in the specs.  I am newer to specs in general.  I tried changing @ user = current_user to @ user = User.find(params[:id]) in the controller, but now I get an error saying Couldn't find User without an ID

Comment: Also I am using devise - which is where the current_user method comes from.  I included devise helpers in spec helpers, but this is where the error appears to be coming from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it was a static pages controller, in which a user existed sometimes, and other times a user did not exist yet.  So if I changed the variable to only to be relevant if the user is signed_in it works.

```
def home
  @courses = current_user.courses if signed_in?
end
```